# Laravel 5.6: Getting Call to undefined method ...\Store::getToken() after upgrading composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-upgrade

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I am getting:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken() after upgrading composer.json

Answer (score 2):

The change was made in this commit https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/66976ba3f559ee6ede4cc865ea995996cd42ee1b

In [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0) (for Laravel 5.4) you can read:

> All calls to the ->getToken() method should be changed to ->token().

So this can be easily fix according to above info

Comment: I am not able to find getToken() method , I am using laravel 5.6

Comment: @ApoorvSrivastava As I said in Laravel 5.4 method `getToken` was replaced by `token` method. You should use `token()` method instead of `getToken()`. In Laravel 5.6 is the same.